# Issue with bind command, cannot bind dut to interface

Tags: system-verilog

Please help to figure out the issue which I am facing when using bind command, to bind my DUT to interface. I am not able to bind my dut signals to interface signals. The simulator keeps giving the errors.

I have a feeling that I need to define all my DUT ports as input/output ports of the interface for bind command to work.
This is my code:

```
module top();
…

trfcCtrlItf itf (clock);

trafficController dut
    (hwy, hwy_wlk, cntry, cntry_wlk, 
    cntrRdCarsNmb, 
    setup, done, 
    clock, clear);

bindModule bind_inst(clock);
…
endmodule

module bindModule (input bit clk);

 bind trafficController trfcCtrlItf bind_inst 
    (hwy, hwy_wlk, cntry, cntry_wlk, 
    cntrRdCarsNmb, 
    setup, done, 
    clock, clear);  

endmodule

module trafficController
    (hwy, hwy_wlk, cntry, cntry_wlk, 
    cntrRdCarsNmb, 
    setup, done, 
    clock, clear);

output reg [1:0] hwy, cntry;
output reg [1:0] hwy_wlk, cntry_wlk; 
input setup, done;
input clock, clear;
input[5:0] cntrRdCarsNmb;   
…
endmodule

interface trfcCtrlItf (input bit clock);

logic clear;
logic [1:0] hwy, cntry;
logic [1:0] hwy_wlk, cntry_wlk;
logic setup, done;
logic [5:0] cntrRdCarsNmb;

modport dut (input clock, clear, setup, done, cntrRdCarsNmb, 
             output hwy, cntry, hwy_wlk, cntry_wlk);

modport tb (output clock, clear, setup, done, cntrRdCarsNmb, 
            input hwy, cntry, hwy_wlk, cntry_wlk);
endinterface
```

Simulator gives error on bind module saying that too many port connections

> ## ** Fatal: (vsim-3365) E:/Documents/SystemVerilog/UVM_Reg_myExample_trfcCntrl/bindModule.sv(15):
>
> Too many port connections. Expected 1, found 9.

Please please only don’t send this article as an answer:
http://events.dvcon.org/2012/proceedings/papers/01P_3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
bind trafficController trfcCtrlItf bind_inst
```

means bind an instance of (the interface) `trfcCtrlItf` into the module `trafficController` with the instance name `bind_inst`. The interface `trfcCtrlItf` only has one port, but in this statement you are connecting 9 ports:

```
 bind trafficController trfcCtrlItf bind_inst 
    (hwy, hwy_wlk, cntry, cntry_wlk, 
    cntrRdCarsNmb, 
    setup, done, 
    clock, clear);
```

Hence your error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer
Actually I kind of dont like this approach... let me justify my opinion
The idea of interface to simplify the modules connections e.g. easly add/remove module ports
but now each time when we change some port in module we have to 
a) edit interface file
b) edit binding module
dont see clear benefit of using interface module in this case